# Why is this for loop reverting to 0 and never getting to the end of the size of this array

Tags: javascript

This problem refers to the hackerank anagram question here:
[image: String Anagram]

For some reason, this for loop never completes. It gets to 3 (-2 from the length of the array it is iterating over) and then goes back to 0 and I can't tell why.

```js
const dictionary = ['hack', 'a' , 'rank' , 'khac','ackh']
const query = ['a','nark','bs','hack','stair']

console.log(stringAnagram(dictionary, query))

function stringAnagram(dictionary, query){
    let sortedDictionary=[];
    let sortedQuery = [];
    let alphabetisedWord;
    let sortedWord;
    let anagramsCount = [];
    // sort them
    for(let i = 0; i<dictionary.length-1; i++){
        sortedWord= dictionary[i];
        if(dictionary[i].length > 1){
         sortedWord= sortedWord.split('');
        console.log('sortedWord: ',sortedWord)
            sortedWord= sortedWord.sort();
            console.log('sortedWord: ',sortedWord)
            sortedWord= sortedWord.join('');
            console.log('sortedWord: ',sortedWord)

            sortedDictionary[i] = sortedWord;
        } else {
            sortedDictionary[i] = sortedWord;
        }
        console.log(i, dictionary.length)
    }
    
    for(let i = 0; i<query.length-1; i++){
        alphabetisedWord = query[i];
        if(query[i].length > 1){

        
        alphabetisedWord = alphabetisedWord.split('');
        console.log('alpha : ', alphabetisedWord)
        alphabetisedWord = alphabetisedWord.sort();
        alphabetisedWord = alphabetisedWord.join('');
        }

        var regex = new RegExp("/" + alphabetisedWord + "/", "g");
        console.log(stringAnagram(dictionary, query))
        anagramsCount[i] = sortedDictionary.toString().match(regex).length
        sortedQuery[i] = alphabetisedWord;
    }
    
    
    return anagramsCount;

}
```

Can anyone tell what's causing this? I have tried logging all the indexes and words but I did a similar question earlier with a similar method of answering - only this time, the endless loop has appeared and I have never seen this before.

Comment: You don't add `/` to a regex string when you construct it with the `RegExp` constructor. If you do, it means you want to match the "/" character literally.

Comment: Also, `console.log(stringAnagram(dictionary, query))` is a recursive call to the function, and that will effectively be an infinite loop.

Comment: Is it? Thats how I called my other anagram function with no issues. DOes it not just get log the returned value of the function given the args for dictionary and query? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 54,
  "colno": 68
}` when fixing the two comments above - the line is `anagramsCount[i] = sortedDictionary.toString().match(regex).length` - also why `-1` in `i<query.length-1` ?

Comment: try to take off the `-1` and leave `i<dictionary.length` for example `for(let i = 0; i<dictionary.length-1; i++){`

Comment: @TheBombSquad this has no effect, I tried adding the -1 in case that would fix the problem from before

Comment: huh... interesting.. gonna dive in then

Comment: alright. what r u trying to do.. what result r u trying to get(yea im thinking of just forgetting that loop and doing something different to solve the REAL problem)

Comment: calling, unconditionally, `stringAnagram()` from *inside* `stringAnagram()` is an infinitely recursive sequence.

Comment: ah I didn't see the console.log(stringAnagram() inside the actual function! Thanks for pointing that out. Sadly this regex is still not working - anyone know how to fix it so that its a dynamic regex which matches itself up to the words in the dictionary array?

Comment: 5-10 minutes more

Comment: I don't see why you need a regex at all. For two original strings which are anagrams, the sorted character versions will either be equal or not.

Comment: The regex is necessary in order to prevent the need for another for loop which would then render the code at O(n^2) - I need to avoid this.

Comment: the `.match()` call will have to check all the characters of the string, plus you have to construct the regex, which will *also* involve all the characters of the alphabetized string. A plain string comparison is cheaper.

Comment: @Marcooz2007 I just went and skipped straight to the problem.. gonna edit it so it shows anagrams in like 5 more mins(forgot to do 1 thing)

Comment: @Marcooz2007 i think i solved it

Comment: just checking up @Marcooz2007 did it work?

Answer (score 1):

If a simple problem seems impossible, you're doing it a wrong way... eek talking to myself too

```js
const dictionary = ['hack', 'a' , 'rank' , 'khac','ackh']
const query = ['a','nark','bs','hack','stair']

console.log(stringAnagram(dictionary, query))

function stringAnagram(dd,qq){
  var j=(x)=>{return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))} //function to ensure an object isn't passed as pointer JUST IN CASE and to that dude critisizing this part, stringifying an already correctly evaluated obj works(therefore parsing that would be parsing a correctly stringified obj)
  var d=j(dd); var q=j(qq)
  //make words in both query and dictionary now have their words in only 1 format(so that indexOf would work like a charm)
  d=d.map(a=>{return a.split``.sort().join``})
  q=q.map(a=>{return a.split``.sort().join``})
  //now onto indexOf logic(returns the FIRST find of what ur looking for in an array)
  var arr=[]
  q.forEach(a=>{
    var i=0
    while(d.indexOf(a)!=-1){
      var y=d.indexOf(a)
      i++;d.splice(y,1)
    }
    arr.push(i)
  })
  return(arr)
}
```

Comment: You should declare `j` with `let` or `const` or something.

Comment: im splicing from one of the things.. now javascript has a nice way of passing objects as pointers and not copies, for 2

Comment: You didn't declare `j` **at all**; you created a global variable.

Comment: It is universally considered terrible practice to not declare variables. I mean, you do it with all the other variables in the function.

Comment: fine.. `window.j` :l

Comment: but **why** pollute the global namespace for a function that's only relevant in that limited context?

Comment: Also note that `JSON.stringify()` can *fail*. Not all objects can be stringified.

Comment: Hello, @TheBombSquad please read the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Also, comments aren't for extended discussion please move this conversation to a chat.